# How to format `docker ps` command into a list of dictionaries

Tags: json, docker, ps

When I issue the following command

```
docker ps --no-trunc --format '{"name":"{{.Names}}", "status":"{{.Status}}"}'
```

I get output such as:

```
{"name": "container1", "status": "Up 10 hours"}
{"name": "container2", "status": "Up 10 hours"}
```

Each of these line is a valid JSON object, but I am lazy and want the whole output to be a valid JSON which represents a list of dictionaries:

```
[
{"name": "container1", "status": "Up 10 hours"},
{"name": "container2", "status": "Up 10 hours"}
]
```

Is there a way for the `docker ps` command to output in that format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing would be to pipe to `jq -s`:

```
docker ps --no-trunc --format '{"name":"{{.Names}}", "status":"{{.Status}}"}' \
    | jq -s
```

From `jq --help`:

```
-s               read (slurp) all inputs into an array; apply filter to it;
```

---

PS: If you are going to use `jq` anyways, then I suggest the following command instead:

```
docker ps --no-trunc --format '{{ json . }}' \
    | jq -s 'map({name:.Names,status:.Status})'
```

The command is leaving the json serialization to the Go template function `json` instead of doing it manually as in your example. This has the benefit that problematic characters in container names, for example unicode, wouldn't break the json output.

Comment: Right to the point. Thank you.